# What can I do to use Revere Ware copper bottom pots on a glass cooktop?

Tags: equipment, copper-cookware

Only *after* my new GE Profile cooktop was installed did I read the owner's manual which recommended that I not use copper-bottom pots on it.

Is there anything I can do so I can still use my Revere Ware pots? Would a heat diffuser work?

I am more afraid of ruining my cooktop than my pots so I would like a solution that will not compromise my cooktop in anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice GDee! I had made several edits to your question to clarify and improve readibility. Seasoned Advice is a community ran site and this is common practice. If however you feel I have change your meaning in any way, you may edit it farther by clicking on the "edit" link under the tags.

Comment: GE Profile is a whole line of ranges and cooktops, could you please specify the model number?

Answer (score 2):

I'm somewhat confused by your question, as GE appears to recommend copper-bottom cookware. At least if I've grabbed the right manual, lacking a model number.

[image: Selecting types of cookware for radiant glass cooktop models]

Note the word **recommended** right below "copper bottom". Though they do warn you that you have to be diligent cleaning any residues left and not allowing cookware to overheat. (Though, depending on the thickness of that copper bottom, you may find that stainless with an aluminum disc is actually better cookware, and fairly cheap.)

Comment: Profile Model is P945SM3SS. My manual for Copper Bottoms says: "usable but not recommended...may leave residue appearing as scratches...overheated can bond to glass cooktop..." Thanks...I'm buying a set of hard anodized cookware to be on the safe side. Will miss that lovely Revere Ware.  Glad I found this site!

Comment: @GDee Hmm, neither Google nor the GE site know about that model number. Unless you're looking for nonstick, you probably want to consider stainless. Just search the site for "cookware", there are several questions about different types of cookware.

Comment: Sorry--guess I goofed on the Model #. It is PP945SMSS...GE didn't get it when I sent in my registration either...Thanks for the advice.  I'm going for a new set of cookware; have searched and will probably go for stainless steel.